# Optimal sticker pack spend

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

A new set of Disney stickers has arrived! There are 170 stickers to collect to achieve Heart Eyes Child.

The stickers come in packs of 10, at a cost of 8p per sticker, but you can buy specific missing stickers at 27p each.

What is the optimal (cheapest) strategy? Assume you can see one pack at once, and that the sticker distribution is even.

I figured the answer must look something like "buy packs until you reach $x$ fraction incomplete, then buy the individual stickers to complete". I'm thinking x is the point where buying another pack has lower value regarding completion of the set than 27p, which could just be when less than 8/27ths remain?

But what is the expectation value of this strategy? And how would the constraint that packs contain all unique stickers change it?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @user2661923: Genuinely bought a sticker book and wondered how much it would cost, and then realised it was more nuanced than the standard expected number of packs to complete the book.

Comment: If I was attacking the problem, on my own, without the benefit of MathSE, then my starting point would be : [1] Review the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). [2] Find the right book to study Probability Theory and the right book to study Statistics [3] Run computer simulations of various strategies, on a PC, in a language like Java, C, or Python.  Note that your problem is a complicated variant of the basic Coupon Collector's Problem, because the *stickers* come in packs of $(10)$, rather than in packs of $(1)$. ...see next comment

Comment: Personally, I would try to derive an analytic solution, based on the (false) premise that stickers come in packs of $(1)$.  Then, I would consider *what if* stickers come in packs of $(k)$, attempting to examine each scenario separately, for each value of $(k) \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, 10\}.$  Alternatively, your problem may be a known problem, for which a MathSE reviewer with a much greater knowledge of Probability/Statistics than I have can give you more effective guidance.